# Midnight hours shows as 24 instead of 00

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, time

```
          var timeNow = new Date();
          var date = timeNow.toLocaleString("en-CA", {
            timeZone: "America/New_York"
          }).split(",")[0];
          var hour = timeNow.toLocaleString("en-CA", {
            hour: "2-digit",
            hour12: false,
            timeZone: "America/New_York"
          }) + ":00:00";
```

I am using en-CA for the format of the date I want. However, I just found a tricky bug. It shows 12:12 AM of today as 24:12 of today. It is creating bugs in other libraries like js plotlib.

Why are the hours shown as 24 and not 00 for the first hour of the day? I can't just subtract 1 from hours because the date would be wrong then. And it is only an issue for the first hour of the day - 2 pm is still 14.

Thanks!

Example: Posting this as of 2 PM ET
[image]

Comment: _“I can't just subtract 1”_ — Yes. But you can compute the hours modulo 24.

Comment: Clarified the question to show why I can't do that. I understand it is just an if statement to replace 24 with 00 but still curious to understand the underlying issue.

Comment: Currently, `"Asia/Yekaterinburg"` (as an example) has UTC+05:00, so, there, it’s about 00:14:40 now. Still, `hour` is `00:00:00`, not `24:00:00`.

Comment: I posted an example above. Not sure what's going on

Comment: Please post code and data as text, not as pictures of text.

Comment: Okay, your screenshot tells a different story. This results in `00:00:00` on Firefox, but in `24:00:00` on Chrome, as — as I just noticed — the duplicate target also explains.

Comment: Just to clarify from the duplicate:  You can resolve this by using `hourCycle: 'h23'` *instead of* `hour12: false`.